# PHP. Почему добавляется NULL

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Почему при выполнении данного кода:

```
namespace Stark;

class Eddard
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo '123';
    }
}

$eddard = new Eddard();

var_dump($eddard->test());
```

Я в результате получаю: **123NULL**

Откуда NULL берется?

Comment: ну у тебя выполнилось `echo` так? а оно [ничего не возвращает](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-returnvalues).... а чему равно "ничто"? NULL. вот тебе var_dump и выводит

Comment: Попробуй изучить любой строго типизированный язык, такие вопросы отпадут сами по себе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `test` ничего не возвращает явно - в нём нету конструкции `return (выражение);`. А когда метод (или функция) в php ничего не возвращает явно, интерпретатор за вас возвращает `null`.

`var_dump()` этот `null` и выводит.

Следующий код эквивалентен вашему:

```
namespace Stark;

class Eddard
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo '123'; // выводится до выполнения var_dump
        return null; // подразумевается интерпретатором. null берется отсюда
    }
}

$eddard = new Eddard();

var_dump($eddard->test());
```